# Why is model.fit working without clear attribute and label separation and the same method is not working for model.evaluate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am working on building DistillBERT model for IMDB dataset where the text is classified either as positive or negative. In my code I have first tokenised the 'text' data -

```
from datasets import load_dataset
imdb = load_dataset("imdb")

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

def preprocess_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], truncation=True)

tokenized_imdb = imdb.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
```

After this I have added padding and converted the dataset to TF dataset.

```
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")

import tensorflow as tf
tf_train_set = tokenized_imdb["train"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "label"],
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=16,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
)

tf_validation_set = tokenized_imdb["test"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "label"],
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=16,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
)

from transformers import create_optimizer

batch_size = 16
num_epochs = 5
batches_per_epoch = len(tokenized_imdb["train"]) // batch_size
total_train_steps = int(batches_per_epoch * num_epochs)
optimizer, schedule = create_optimizer(init_lr=2e-5, num_warmup_steps=0, 
num_train_steps=total_train_steps)

from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base- 
uncased", num_labels=2)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,metrics=. 
['accuracy','sparse_categorical_accuracy','AUC','precision','recall'])
```

Then, I am trying to find out the base case accuracy of the pre-trained model for the same dataset as with which fine-tuning will be done, i.e., the model's accuracy before fine-tuning it for the downstream task.

```
base_model_result= model.evaluate(x=tf_validation_set) 

print(base_model_result)
```

This is where I am getting the error -

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

This clearly means that I need to provide attribute and label values separately.
However, this same strategy is working fine for model.fit

```
results = model.fit(x=tf_train_set, validation_data=tf_validation_set, epochs=3)
```

Now if I need to split tf_validation_set, how can I do that and make model.validation work. I have tried converting tf_validation_set to a list but it's still not working.

For resolving this issue I tried converting the tf dataset to list and then separate the attributes and the label column like so -

```py
X = list(map(lambda x: [x['input_ids'],x['attention_mask']], tf_validation_set))
y = list(map(lambda x: x['labels'], tf_validation_set))

base_loss, base_acc = model.evaluate(X,y,verbose=1) 

print('Base accuracy:', base_acc)
```

But here I am getting following error -

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input data could be:

- A `Numpy array` (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A TensorFlow `tensor`, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A `dict` mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.
- A `tf.data dataset`. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
- A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

The "input data" or the parameter "x" in the fit()/evaluate() method passed to the model is of type `tf.data` dataset that returns a  tuple of either `(inputs, targets)` or `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.
If "x" is a `tf.data` dataset instance, "y" should not be specified (since targets will be obtained from x). Kindly, refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) for more information.

Your code is working fine in Colab, please find the gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/9a7f360775ffb936394762bf10c563fa/73046919.ipynb). Thank you!